# How do I remove time from the date so I can compare two dates?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have xml with two elements both displaying date. However one displays date with time on it while the other does not have time. 
I would like to compare the two date but I need to strip the time leaving date only.
How do I do this?
In my vb program, I want to check if `stOrderDAte <= strmessageProducedDateTime`

**Here is my xml elements with the date:**

```xml
<OrderEndDate>2015-08-06</OrderEndDate>
<DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification messageProducedDateTime="2015-08-07T17:25:12-05:00" xmlns="http://www.courts.state.mn.us/CourtXML/3">
```

**Here is my vb code:**

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(ByRef aobjBroker As MessageBroker.Library.v4.Broker, _
    ByRef aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc As System.Xml.XmlDocument, ByRef aobjInstantiatedObjectsCollection As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection)
        MyBase.ProcessMessage(aobjBroker, aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc, aobjInstantiatedObjectsCollection)

        Dim strSoapText As String
        Dim strNotificationEvent As String
        Dim strOrderEndDate As String
        Dim objNameTable As NameTable
        Dim objXMLNameSpaceManager As XmlNamespaceManager
        Dim strmessageProducedDateTime As String
        Dim strErrorDescription As String

        'create a namespace manager used for queries into inputmessage (because of namespace)
        objNameTable = New NameTable
        objXMLNameSpaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(objNameTable)
        objXMLNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
        objXMLNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("wsa", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing")
        objXMLNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("msc", "http://www.courts.state.mn.us/CourtXML/3")

        strSoapText = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Reason/soap:Text", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        strNotificationEvent = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification/msc:NotificationEvent", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        strOrderEndDate = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrder/msc:OrderEndDate", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        strmessageProducedDateTime = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification/@messageProducedDateTime", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        strErrorDescription = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/ErrorDescription", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText

        If (strNotificationEvent = "OrderDeleted") And (strOrderEndDate <= strmessageProducedDateTime) Or (strErrorDescription = "Protection Order Number does not exist on an 'OrderDeleted' transaction.") Then
            aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Deleting an expired DANCO. No outstanding failure", 1)
        ElseIf (strOrderEndDate <= strmessageProducedDateTime) And (strErrorDescription = "Protection Order Number does not exist on an ‘Order Modified’ transaction.") Then 
            aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Skipping pass when modifying expired DANCO. No outstanding failure", 1)            
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Rejection_From_BCA")

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Comparing two strings that represent a date is guaranteed to end badly. Instead try to convert the strings to an appropriate DateTime variable, then compare just the Date part.

Comment: How do I convert it Steve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String =
           "<Root>" & _
               "<OrderEndDate>2015-08-06</OrderEndDate>" & _
               "<DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification messageProducedDateTime=""2015-08-07T17:25:12-05:00"" xmlns="""">" & _
               "</DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification>" & _
           "</Root>"

        Dim element As XElement = XElement.Parse(input)

        Dim orderEndDate As DateTime = element.Descendants("OrderEndDate").Select(Function(x) (CType(x.Value, String))).FirstOrDefault()
        Dim messageProducedDateTime As DateTime = element.Descendants("DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("messageProducedDateTime").Value
        Dim _time As TimeSpan = messageProducedDateTime.TimeOfDay
    End Sub

End Module
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys were right in comments, I give credit to them. Here you have code sample, just supply strings `input1` and `input2`:

```vb
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
If DateTime.TryParse(OrderEndDate, date1) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(messageProducedDateTime, date2) Then
    If date1.Date < date2.Date Then 
        'do something
    Else
        'do something else
    End If
Else
    'throw error that one of dates cannot be parsed
End If
```

---

In your code

Replace two of your declarations with:

```vb
Dim orderEndDate As DateTime
Dim messageProducedDateTime As DateTime
```

And use this code:

```vb
strSoapText = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Reason/soap:Text", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
strNotificationEvent = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification/msc:NotificationEvent", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
orderEndDate = DateTime.Parse(aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrder/msc:OrderEndDate", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText)
messageProducedDateTime = DateTime.Parse(aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification/@messageProducedDateTime", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText)
strErrorDescription = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/ErrorDescription", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText


If (strNotificationEvent = "OrderDeleted") And bothDatesPresent And (orderEndDate <= messageProducedDateTime.Date) Or (strErrorDescription = "Protection Order Number does not exist on an 'OrderDeleted' transaction.") Then
    aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Deleting an expired DANCO. No outstanding failure", 1)
ElseIf (orderEndDate <= messageProducedDateTime.Date) And (strErrorDescription = "Protection Order Number does not exist on an ‘Order Modified’ transaction.") Then 
    aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Skipping pass when modifying expired DANCO. No outstanding failure", 1)            
Else
    Throw New Exception("Rejection_From_BCA")
End If
```

If there are any issues with parsing the date, please research [Date.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to parse various date formats.

Apart of this, your code has these minor issues:

- Consider replacing of `And`/`Or` operators with `AndAlso`/`OrElse`.
- In VB.NET, do not use variable prefixes, i.e. use `soapText` instead of `strSoapText`.

Comment: I follow what you suggested, however I am not sure how to do it in my vb program

Comment: I was told date will always be there. I was asked to convert it on this line of code `strmessageProducedDateTime = aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/msc:DomesticAbuseNoContactOrderNotification/@messageProducedDateTime", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText`

Comment: You can get just time with TimeOfDay() method.  See my answer.